# Adding a product using Savon to connect to Magento API

Tags: ruby, magento, savon

I have got the code working for listing products in Ruby but am struggling to add a product, here is my code, I’m using the savon gem for HTTP/SOAP requests, based on the code here http://www.polyvision.org/2011/10/02/using-magento-soap-api-with-ruby-and-savon/

```
# Insert some products ...

newproductdata = [ 
["name" , “test product"], 
["websites" , [1]], 
["short_description" , ‘short description’], 
["description" , ‘description’], 
["status" , 1], 
["weight" , 0], 
["tax_class_id" , 1], 
["categories" , [3]], 
["price" , 12.05] 
]

begin 
  response = client.request :call do 
    soap.body = {:session => session, :method => “product.create”, :arguments => ["simple", 1, “testsku1”, newproductdata]} 
  end 
rescue Savon::SOAP::Fault => fault 
  puts “*****#{fault.to_s}*****” 
end
```

I think the issue is the passing in of :arguments which perhaps needs to be named correctly, this code generates the error,

```
(SOAP-ENV:Client) Error cannot find parameter
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are mixing array- [] and hash-syntax {}

that's why you get a SYNTAX error (there is no COMPILATION step in ruby)

Comment: Any idea why, if I change the code to soap.body = {:session => session, :method => "product.create", ["simple", 1, "testsku1", newproductdata ]} I get the same error in that case?

Comment: Ah, it's newproductdata that needs to be a hash?

Comment: a hash is like {:key => 'value', ...} and an array is ['val1', 'val2', 'val3'] i guess you should start with the basics before using some advanced library...