# Filter products with API Magento in Ruby on Rails with Savon gem (SOAP)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, magento, savon

I am using [this code](http://www.polyvision.org/2011/10/02/using-magento-soap-api-with-ruby-and-savon.html) for my rails app with the API of Magento. Everything is fine except for one thing, i need filter the products by arguments of the Magento API but i don't know how :(

Obviously i have tested with more solutions (array, hash, etc), but
unsuccessful.

Pd: Sorry, my english is very limited

Links

- Related case (fail): [Adding a product using Savon to connect to Magento API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7634928/adding-a-product-using-savon-to-connect-to-magento-api)
- Example: http://www.polyvision.org/2011/10/02/using-magento-soap-api-with-ruby-and-savon.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know this is very late, but if anyone else is finding this thread, I've created a magento_api_wrapper gem that implements filters for the Magento SOAP API v2. You can find the code here: https://github.com/harrisjb/magento_api_wrapper

To summarize, if you want to use one of the Magento SOAP API simple filters, you can pass a hash with a key and value:

```
api = MagentoApiWrapper::Catalog.new(magento_url: "yourmagentostore.com/index.php", magento_username: "soap_api_username", magento_api_key: "userkey123")

api.product_list(simple_filters: [{key: "status", value: "processing"}, {key: created_at, value: "12/10/2013 12:00" }])
```

And to use a complex filter, pass a hash with key, operator, and value:

```
api.product_list(complex_filters: [{key: "status", operator: "eq", value: ["processing", "completed"]}, {key: created_at, operator: "from", value: "12/10/2013" }])
```

Answer (score 3):

Spent ages getting this to work with Savon - there are no actual solutions on the web. Went and looked at the SOAP call and was missing :item

```
params = {:filter => {:item => {:key => "status", :value => "closed"}}}

result = client.call(:sales_order_list, message: { session_id: session_id, filters: params})
```

This will only return orders that are of status closed.

Comment: great! Work to me! when is need apply more than one filter?

Comment: It worked for me for catalog product list API. Thanks!!

As @IsmaelVacco mentioned, not sure how to use multiple filters. Trying `[{:filter => {:item => {:key => "status", :value => "1"}}}, {:filter => {:item => {:key => "type", :value => "grouped"}}}]` doesn't work. It just applies first filters from the list

Comment: `filters: [{:filter=>{:item=>[{:key=>"status", :value=>"1"}, {:key=>"type", :value=>"simple"}]}}]` worked for multiple filters

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to work with Magento and Rails, Gemgento might be what you need.  It replaces Magento's front end with RoR.

http://www.gemgento.com

After you sync with Magento you can use the `Gemgento::Product.filter` method along with some scopes to easily search the EAV structure of Magento.

```
attribute = Gemgento::Attribute.find_by(code: 'color')
Gemgento::Product.filter({ attribute: attribute, value: 'red' })
```

The filter method can actually take all sorts of array/hash combos

```
filters = [
   { attribute: [attribute1, attribute2], value: %w[red yellow black] },
   { attribute: size_attribute, value: 'L' }
]
Gemgento::Product.filter(filters)
```

Comment: Massively expensive though.